# which solution should i use to build an app?

Tags: cordova, titanium, local-storage

You've probably heard this a million times, but i think i got a pretty cool idea for an app.

The problem is that i don't no where to start, which tool is best and can give me what i want.

My skills:
- HTML, CSS, jQuery

What my app needs:
- Local database to store text and photos (or links to that photo, that will be stored in a folder)
- Camera access
- GPS access (this might not make v1)

How my database would globally look like:
- User add an event
- In event: Add sub events
- In sub event: Add text and/or photo

User can see his events in a table or something.

Should i go with phonegap or something? Or titanium? or something completly else?

And what's a good starting point? I've tried Phonegap for half an our, but i'm already stuck with the database, i don't see anything happen.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Compare the features of the libraries you suggested, and take decision yourself.

Comment: Pick something, verify it meets the requirements, then learn how to use it; this sort of "shopping" question isn't a good fir for SO.

Comment: Please only post questions related to programming issues and/or debugging help in stack overflow. This type of question can be answered with a google search.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Christophe Coenraets' blog](http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/), it doesn't really detail the database part but it provides samples you can play with that contain different implementations of local data storage for phonegap apps.